# How to concatenate two arrays?

Tags: arrays, vala, genie

```
[indent=4]

init
    x: array of int = {1, 2, 3}
    y: array of int = {4, 5, 6}
    z: array of int = x + y
```

The above code produces this error message:

```
concat_arrays.gs:6.23-6.27: error: Incompatible operand
    z: array of int = x + y
```

The Vala translation doesn't work any better:

```
int main () {
    int[] x = {1, 2, 3};
    int[] y = {4, 5, 6};
    int[] z = x + y;
    return 0;
}
```

The error message is:

```
concat_arrays_v.vala:4.15-4.19: error: Incompatible operand
    int[] z = x + y;
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `GLib.Array<T>`:

```
int main () {
    int[] x = {1, 2, 3};
    int[] y = {4, 5, 6};
    Array<int> a = new Array<int> (false, true, 0);
    a.append_vals (x, x.length);
    a.append_vals (y, y.length);
    // taking over ownership avoids array copying
    int[] z = (owned) a.data; 

    foreach (var i in z) {
        stdout.printf ("%d ", i);
    }
    stdout.printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The Genie version:

```
[indent=4]

init
    x: array of int = {1, 2, 3}
    y: array of int = {4, 5, 6}
    var a = new Array of int (false, true, 0)
    a.append_vals (x, x.length)
    a.append_vals (y, y.length)
    z: array of int = (owned) a.data
```

**Update**: After [answering this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31386774/genie-why-this-function-return-an-owned-value) I have modified the above code to use `(owned)` which avoids an uneccessary array copy operation.

The `new Array<T>` still adds some overhead for allocating an object, but that should be no problem in most cases.

Using `Memory.copy` is dangerous as it can cause all sorts of memory problems.

Comment: Is this still the way to got? Looks complicated to just append one array to another.

Comment: It is the easiest way to add two plain arrays that I know of, yes. There are more flexible data types you can use though like Gee.ArrayList (which has a add_all () method).