# Genie how to return an array of unowned strings

Tags: vala, genie

how to return an **array** of **unowned strings** that all point to the same location in memory?

example:

```
init
    var str = "ABC"
    var unowned_string_array = repeat (str, 5)

def repeat (s: string, n: int): array of string
    // code
```

and this array will contains 5 elements(same string "ABC"), all point to same location

Comment: I have tried do solve this, but the syntax is tricky here. I have found a relevant mailing list post here: http://osdir.com/ml/vala-list/2009-12/msg00046.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest Vala code I could get is:

```
int main() {
    var str = "ABC";
    var unowned_string_array = repeat (str, 5);
    return 0;
}

public (unowned string)[] repeat (string s, int n) {
    var a = new (unowned string)[n];
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
        // This sadly still duplicates the string,
        // even though a should be an array of unowned strings
        a[i] = s; 
    return a;
}
```

I'm not sure if the compiler understands the parenthesis here, it may think that I want to declare an unowned array of owned strings here ...

**Update:** It turns out the problem is that type inference will always create an owned variable (see nemequs comment).

There is even a [bug report for this](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=638199).

So this works just fine (no string duplication in the `repeat` function):

```
int main() {
    var str = "ABC";
    (unowned string)[] unowned_string_array = repeat (str, 5);
    return 0;
}

public (unowned string)[] repeat (string s, int n) {
    (unowned string)[] a = new (unowned string)[n];
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
        // This sadly still duplicates the string,
        // even though a should be an array of unowned strings
        a[i] = s;
    return a;
}
```

Which would be something like this in Genie:

```
[indent=4]

init
    var str = "ABC"
    unowned_string_array: array of (unowned string) = repeat (str, 5)

def repeat (s: string, n: int): array of (unowned string)
    a: array of (unowned string) = new array of (unowned string)[n]
    for var i = 1 to n
        a[i] = s
    return a
```

The Genie code has the additional problem of not compiling, due to the parser not being able to deduce what comes after the `array of`.

This seems to be a similar problem to what I already had with [nested generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358261/what-is-the-syntax-for-nested-generic-types-in-genie).

I have [reported this a Genie bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=752364).

Comment: By default all variables are owned—when you use type inferencing you are creating a new *owned* variable, even if the right hand side is unowned.  If you do `(unowned string)[] a = new (unowned string)[n];` you can avoid the `g_strdup`.  No idea about genie, though, sorry.  owned arrays of unowned values are a newish (a couple years old, IIRC) feature in Vala, I wouldn't be surprised if Genie hasn't been updated.

Comment: So should we file a bug report for this on the vala compiler?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt.  TBH I'm not familiar enough with genie to tell you definitively that there isn't a way to do what you're asking, but it seems likely that would be the syntax…